# jqplot - Want to restrict y axis ticks

Tags: javascript, css, jqplot

In below code y axis values are not readable, I guess its overlapping.
How to set suitable y axis tick range:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var line1 = [82,82];
            var line2 = [22,22];
            var line3 = [0,0];


 var ticks = [1,2];$.jqplot('line', [line1, line2, line3], {
    animate: true,
    axesDefaults:{min:0,tickInterval: 1},        
    seriesDefaults: {
        rendererOptions: {
            smooth: true
        }
    },
    series: [{lineWidth: 1.5, label: 'Passed'},
        {lineWidth: 1.5, label: 'Failed'},
        {lineWidth: 1.5, label: 'Skipped'}],
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: "Run Number",
            ticks: ticks,
            tickOptions: {

                formatString: "%'d Run"

            },
            pad: 1.2,
            rendererOptions: {
                tickInset: 0.3,
                minorTicks: 1
            }
        },
        yaxis: {

            label: "TC Number me"

            ,tickOptions: {
                formatString: "%'d Tc"
                },
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 10,
        tooltipLocation: 'n',
        tooltipAxes: 'y',
        tooltipFormatString: '%d :&nbsp;<b><i><span style="color:black;">Test Cases</span></i></b>',
        useAxesFormatters: false
    },
    cursor: {
        show: true
    },
    grid: {background: '#ffffff', drawGridLines: true, gridLineColor: '#cccccc', borderColor: '#cccccc',
        borderWidth: 0.5, shadow: false},
    legend: {show: true, placement: 'outside', location: 'e'},
    seriesColors: ["#7BB661", "#E03C31", "#21ABCD"]
});
});
```

[image: Current graph with Y axis values problem]

Answer (score 1):

You have either to remove the **tickInterval** option in axesDefaults to let jqplot computes his own ticks or add the **numberTicks** option in axesDefaults in order to tell jqplot to draw x ticks where x is the number given to the numberTicks option.

- If you use **axesDefaults:{min:0, tickInterval:1}**, jqplot will draw ticks from 0 to your maximal value with an interval of 1 unit (80+ ticks from 0 to 82).
- If you use **axesDefaults:{min:0}**, jqplot will draw 5 ticks (by default) from 0 to your maximal value computing a same gap between two ticks.
- If you use **axesDefaults:{min:0, tickInterval:1, numberTicks:15}**, jqplot will draw 15 ticks starting at 0 and with an interval of 1 unit (15 ticks from 0 to 14).
- If you use **axesDefaults:{min:0, numberTicks:15}**, jqplot will draw 15 ticks from 0 to your maximal value computing a same gap between two ticks.

Choose the option which best fits.