# Primefaces LineChart is not showing correct date values (Google Chrome)

Tags: java, tomcat, charts, primefaces, apache-tomee

I am having trouble using Primefaces Chart with Google Chrome. I would like to show a  series of values (Y-axis) according to specific dates (X-axis). Unfortunately the values for the date (X-Axis) are not shown correctly in Google Chrome (Firefox and Internet Explorer works well).

Below is a small example demonstrating the issue.

**xhtml:**

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartViewController.chartData}" style="height: 300px"/>
```

**ChartViewController.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ChartViewController implements Serializable {


    public LineChartModel getChartData() {
        LineChartModel lineChartModel = new LineChartModel();
        LineChartSeries dataSeries = new LineChartSeries();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        dataSeries.setLabel("Data");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -200*24);
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            dataSeries.set(sdf.format(cal.getTime()), i);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
        }

        /* Add values for y axis */
        lineChartModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
        lineChartModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Values");
        lineChartModel.addSeries(dataSeries);

        DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Datum");
        axis.setTickAngle(-50);
        axis.setMax(sdf.format(new Date()));
        axis.setTickInterval("3 weeks");
        axis.setTickFormat("%d.%m.%y");
        lineChartModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
        lineChartModel.setZoom(true);

        return lineChartModel;
    }
}
```

In Internet Explorer I see the results I am expecting:

[Screenshot Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkwEV.png)

However, showing the same Chart in Google Chrome results in the following picture:

[Screenshot Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obgbI.png)

I also checked my locale settings in Chrome but they look right so far.

Versions used:

- Google Chrome Browser Version 72.0.3626.121 (64-Bit)
- InternetExplorer 11 (also working with Edge)
- Primefaces 6.2 (also tested with 6.3-Snapshot)
- Bootsfaces 1.4.0
- Apache Tomee 7.1

I would be very helpful if somebody have a clue why this happens and how to fix it. First I thought about some timezone / locales issue but currently I am fully aimless.

Thank you for your assistance!

**Update**

When removeing the tickInterval I get the following picture in Google Chrome:

[Google Chrome result without tickInterval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZALd.png)

It looks like the Date is interpreted in US format not the German locale (03.09.2019 vs. 09.03.2019)

**Update**
OK, it seems to work now.

I changed the values for X-Axis to long values from the Date() object and now Google Chrome and Internet Explorer show the same values:

```
dataSeries.set(sdf.format(cal.getTime()), i);
...
axis.setMax(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

to

```
dataSeries.set(cal.getTime().getTime(), i);
...
axis.setMax((new Date()).getTime());
```

Thank you guys for your input!

Comment: What is really strange is IE is show Aug 29 2018 - March 03 2019 but Chrome is showing an entirely different date range?  Chrome is starting an entire YEAR before starting Dec 09, 2017?  So to me this does not make sense it looks almost like two entirely different datasets.

Comment: It looks like you might need the numberTicks option from JqPlot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148162/jqplot-want-to-restrict-y-axis-ticks

Comment: I removed the tickInterval to let primefaces choose a valid range. Unfortunately it did not fix it.

Comment: That is really bizarre.

Comment: Chrome (Google) is becoming bizarre. More and more they go their own way and M$ with their new browser switching to the same 'engine' s*cks...

Comment: OK the timezone issue looks like a known issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1954

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought. I then adjusted the timezone/locales of my Apache Tomee to the same timezone/locales my Browser is using. Unfortunately that didn't fix the result :(